# Could not post request in swift

Tags: php, ios, swift

I am trying post request in swift. I did successfully in objective-C but using swift I could not send request.  `$emailOK` in PHP could not get information. where is the problem? thanks for helper. here is swift code

```
func httpPost1(url:String, postData: String, completion: String -> Void) {
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url)!)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        let postString = postData
        request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
            guard error == nil && data != nil else {                                                          // check for fundamental networking error
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            if let httpStatus = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse where httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
                print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                print("response = \(response)")
            }

            let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            print("responseString = \(responseString)")
        }
        task.resume()
        }
```

here is excution code

```
httpPost1("xxxxx", postData: "emailOK=Hello") { result in

                print(result)//result is your string-response from server

            }
```

Here is my php code

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $username, $dbpass, $database);

if (!$link) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}

echo "Success: A proper connection to MySQL was made! The my_db database is great." . PHP_EOL;
echo "Host information: " . mysqli_get_host_info($link) . PHP_EOL;


$emailOK = isset($_GET["emailOK"]) ? $_GET["emailOK"] : '';

echo $emailOK;

$query = "INSERT INTO UserInfo VALUES ('', '$emailOK')";
mysqli_query($link, $query) or die (mysqli_error("error"));


mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: Why are you using `$_GET` while you are testing POST request?

Comment: @OOPer  I changed to post form get, It worked, thanks man.

Comment: Thanks for reporting, happy to hear that. Please write an answer by yourself if you can make some time to. Good luck for you and for your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, thanks for @OOPer comment. the problem is in PHP `$emailOK = isset($_GET["emailOK"]) ? $_GET["emailOK"] : '';` It should be `$emailOK = $_POST['emailOK'];`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to create session object. I am not sure whether this will completely resolve your issue,but I think you should give it a try.

```
let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)
```

Comment: It might be issues with content type try with below content type or some other.

`request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to send the email as part of url, you should include it in URL:

```
var requestURL = url + "?" + postData

let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url)!)
```

But since you are sending a POST request, it's usually sent in HTTP body. Quite common way is to send it in JSON format:

```
let dict = ["emailOK" : "Hello"]
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
do {
   request.HTTPBody = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dict, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted)
} catch _ {
   request.HTTPBody = nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to spend a lot of hours with useless efforts to write your successful get/post request, your best choice's to rely on libraries with all methods that you need.

In my humble opinion, I suggest you **Alamofire**
https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

Otherwise, to complete your request successfully you should specify *Content-Type*, *Content-Type* header information

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

```
    let dict = ["emailOK" : "Hello"]
    let jsonData = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dict, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted)
    let jsonString = NSString(data: jsonData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)! as String
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string:"url")!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    let postString = jsonString
    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
        guard error == nil && data != nil else {                                                          // check for fundamental networking error
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        if let httpStatus = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse where httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(response)")
        }

        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print("responseString = \(responseString)")
    }
    task.resume()
}
```